# What set does this minifigure head come from?

Tags: minifigure-identification, the-lego-movie

I came across this picture:

[image: LEGO minifigure]

I think the body is from [The LEGO Movie Pajamas Emmet polybag](http://brickset.com/sets/5002045-1/Pyjamas-Emmet), but have no idea where the head is from.

Comment: more comment, it's the face on 
twn203: Queasy Man (10244)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's from [Fairground Mixer](http://brickset.com/sets/10244-1/Fairground-Mixer) (10244).

Also, the rest can be had way cheaper than Pyjamas Emmet polybag in the form of [Sleepyhead](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=col06-3) from Collectible Minifig series 6.